# Sitecore page load slowness

Tags: performance-optimization, application-insights, performance-profiling

I'm using Sitecore instance 9.1, Solr 7.2.1, and SXA 1.8.

I have deployed the environment on Azure and while monitoring incoming requests (to CD instance), I've noticed slowness in loading some pages at specific times.

I've explored App Insights and found an unexplainable behavior the request is taking 28.7 seconds while the breakdown of it shows executions of milli-seconds .. How is that possible? and How to explain what's happening during extra 28 seconds on the app service ??

[image]

I've checked the profiler and it shows that the thread is taking only 1042.48 ms .. How is that possible ?

[image]

Comment: Check the profiler trace, the slowness seems to be coming from the request itself and not from any dependency. From the profiler trace, you should be able to identify from where in your code the bottleneck is coming.

Comment: I've checked the profiler and it shows that the thread is taking only 1042.48 ms .. How is that possible ? @MiguelMinoldo, Please check the new snapshot.

Comment: Try by using the diagnostics tool, collect a profiler trace and a memory dump, take those while you reproduce the issue. In the "Availability and Performance" section, you can also look at high CPU and memory analysis that can help troubleshoot the issue.